# How to change the data type of a column without dropping the column with query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column which has a datatype : datetime. But now i want to convert it to datatype varchar. Can i alter the datatype without droppping the column? If yes, then please explain how?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*If ALTER COLUMN doesn't work.*

It is not unusual for alter column to fail because it cannot make the transformation you desire. In this case, the solution is to create a dummy table TableName_tmp, copy the data over with your specialized transformation in the bulk Insert command, drop the original table, and rename the tmp table to the original table's name.  You'll have to drop and recreate the Foreign key constraints and, for performance, you'll probably want to create keys after filling the tmp table.

*Sound like a lot of work?* Actually, it isn't.

If you are using SQL Server, you can make the SQL Server Management Studio do the work for you!

- Bring up your table structure (right-click on the table column and select "Modify")
- Make all of your changes (if the column transformation is illegal, just add your new column - you'll patch it up in a moment).
- Right-click on the background of the Modify window and select "Generate Change Script."  In the window that appears, you can copy the change script to the clipboard.
- Cancel the Modify (you'll want to test your script, after all) and then paste the script into a new query window.
- Modify as necessary (e.g. add your transformation while removing the field from the tmp table declaration) and you now have the script necessary to make your transformation.

Answer (score 95):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn newtype
```

Beware of the limitations of the ALTER COLUMN clause listed in the article

Answer (score 14):

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] MODIFY COLUMN [column name] datatype
```

Comment: This (`modify` instead of `alter`) won't work for MSSQL; it is for MySQL or Oracle or other DBMSes.

Answer (score 10):

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableNameHere ALTER COLUMN YourColumnNameHere VARCHAR(20)
```

Comment: Gives error : Incorrect syntax near 'columnname' on execution.

Comment: @Samiksha, I ran into that when I accidentally dropped the 'COLUMN' after ALTER

Answer (score 10):

Type the below query:

```sql
alter table table_Name alter column column_name datatype
```

e.g.

```sql
alter table Message alter column message nvarchar(1024);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableNameHere ALTER COLUMN YourColumnNameHere VARCHAR(20)
```

Answer (score 6):

With SQL server 2008 and more, using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE [RecipeInventorys] ALTER COLUMN [RecipeName] varchar(550)
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for postgresql 9.0.3

```
 alter table [table name] ALTER COLUMN [column name] TYPE [character varying];
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] ALTER COLUMN [column_name] varchar(150)
```

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE YourTableNameHere ALTER COLUMN YourColumnNameHere VARCHAR(20) this is perfect for change to datatype

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE - Alter table table_name modify(column_name new_DataType);

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY (column_name data_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY COLUMN yourcolumn datatype

Comment: this answer has been given before. Upvote the correct answer instead of repeating it.

Answer (score -2):

```
ALTER tablename MODIFY columnName newColumnType
```

I'm not sure how it will handle the change from datetime to varchar though, so you may need to rename the column, add a new one with the old name and the correct data type (varchar) and then write an update query to populate the new column from the old.

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-alter-table.html

Comment: Gives error : Incorrect syntax near 'columnname' on execution.

Comment: where i wrote columnName you need to be using the name of the column.. are you doing that?  If it still fails it may be an indication that it doesn't work for converting datetime to varchar

Comment: Thats what i am trying to tell you, modify doesnt work for mssql 2005

Comment: Jesse's suggestion of renaming and adding a new column is exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score -4):

```
alter table [table name] remove [present column name] to [new column name.
```

Comment: You're thinking of `ALTER TABLE table_name
  RENAME COLUMN old_name to new_name` which is not what OP was asking for.