# Converting data for whole table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm newbie in SQL and have some questions:

How can I convert columns (in my table with more than 10 000 rows) in my SQL table (I'm using SQL Server 2008):

1. First column is `nvarchar (50)` and containing different string values, for e.g. like `20131211142319` and it's a date and time - `2013/12/11 14:23:19`. How can I convert this value into date & time and affect this on all rows in this column (more than 10 000).
2. And also I have column with numbers, all this numbers start from `# + number` - e.g. `#8339274`. How can I delete character "#" before all numbers in all rows? Note, that numbers in this column have a different length, from 5 characters to 15 characters.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a more elegant solution for the datetime conversion but here you go:

**1. DATETIME conversion**

This assumes your value is always in the same format you specified:

**Example code for you to run**

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(255) = '20131211142319'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@Value,8) + SPACE(1) + STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(@Value,6), 1,     0, REPLICATE('0', 0)),3,0,':'),6,0,':'))
```

This splits the field into two sections, the DATE portion `LEFT(@Value,8)` and then the TIME
`STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(@Value,6), 1, 0, REPLICATE('0', 0)),3,0,':'),6,0,':')`. The TIME portion is essentially just adding in the colon where applicable (see STUFF on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx))so that it returns a value such as:

`20131211 14:23:19` This makes it applicable to directly convert to a DATETIME.

**2. Removing the # from the numbers**

**Example code for you to run**

```
DECLARE @ValueNumber VARCHAR(255) = '#8339274'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@ValueNumber,2,LEN(@ValueNumber))
```

The above statement will take your number and only return data from the 2nd value onwards, excluding the #. See SUBSTRING on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

To make this run on your table, just replace my variable names in the `SELECT` statement with your column names.

**Example using the above on columns in a table:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([DATECOLUMNNAME],8) + 
SPACE(1) + STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT([DATECOLUMNNAME],6), 
1, 0,REPLICATE('0',0)),3,0,':'),6,0,':')) AS [Date],
SUBSTRING([NUMBERCOLUMNNAME],2,LEN([NUMBERCOLUMNNAME])) AS [Number]
FROM [TABLENAME]
```

Replace [DATECOLUMNNAME] with the name of the column that holds your datetime value. Replace the [NUMBERCOLUMNNAME] with the name of the column that holds your number with the #.

Then finally replace [TABLENAME] with your table name that contains those columns.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand how can I use this solution on all rows in table.

Comment: See above edits. Are you wanting to just perform a select or update the data in the table? You cannot update the table with the converted datetime value as your column is a varchar type and not datetime.

Answer (score 0):

try this : below answer is also correct

```
    declare @a nvarchar(50)
    set @a='20131211142319'

    select cast(left(@a,4)+'/'+substring(@a,5,2)+'/'+substring(@a,7,2)+ ' '+ substring(@a,9,2)+':'+substring(@a,11,2)+':' +right(@a,2) as datetime)

output's this --2013-12-11 14:23:19.000    

    declare @a nvarchar(10)

    set @a='#1234567'
    select replace(@a,'#','')

outputs this--1234567
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand how can I use this solution on all rows in table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408825/how-to-change-the-data-type-of-a-column-with-query @murdoqq see the link if it help n do accept the answer by clicking left tick mark