# Alter Column 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.'

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Aim:**

Alter multiple columns from a newly created table

I had the columns I wanted to modify in the code but have chopped it down to one for this example, there is nothing obvious I can see. I have an even number of brackets and so forth. Nothing is more than 200 characters long.

**Code:**

```
DECLARE @tableALTER NVARCHAR(2500)

SET @tableALTER = ' 
(ALTER TABLE ' + @tableName + ' ALTER COLUMN [ID] VARCHAR(200))'
EXEC (@tableALTER)
```

**Using:**

SQL Server Management Studio

**Error:**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Research includes:

[How to change the data type of a column without dropping the column with query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408825/how-to-change-the-data-type-of-a-column-with-query)

Comment: First step of debugging something like this - `PRINT` the complete text rather than `EXEC` it and, if it's not immediately obviously wrong, *show* us that complete text.

Comment: @JapzDivino - they'd be hard pressed to use SSMS to talk to something other than [tag:sql-server]. I've added the tag.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks .. and it seems that the problem is the opening and closing parenthesis inside the dynamic sql :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about removing the opening and closing parenthesis inside the string.. try this..

```
DECLARE @tableALTER NVARCHAR(2500)

SET @tableALTER = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tableName + ' ALTER COLUMN [ID] VARCHAR(200)'
EXEC (@tableALTER)
```

Comment: I was trying to be good with the parenthesis! :-) Oh well changed thanks!