# ALTER COLUMN when table depends on the column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alter-table, alter-column

I'm trying to alter a column type to increase its size but SQL gives me the following message

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'table_name' is dependent on column 'column_name'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN column_name failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

when I run this query

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name VARCHAR (25) NULL;
```

The questions that I found about this problem are either a constraint or a statistic that holds you from updating the column, but here the own table is dependant on the column that I want to edit.

And the column is not used as FK or anything like that.

How can I change the column type?

Comment: Can you provide a repro  for us to test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the data type of a column with query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408825/how-to-change-the-data-type-of-a-column-with-query)

Comment: There is obviously something special about the column that you aren't telling us, because I am able to alter columns in the way that you have described with no problem.

Comment: Can you share the ddl for the table?

Comment: I have a feeling that you have a self referencing constraint on the column you are trying to alter.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understanding what should I post about the table. What is the command that I need to query to get the infos you need? sp_help? Genereate the create script?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that there is a **Computed** or **Calculated** Column in the table whose expression is based on this column? Removing that would solve the issue.

Please post the full DDL for the table in order for us to actually help

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: It is an answer if that is the problem.... There isn't much more to say

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE <schemaName>.<tableName>
ALTER COLUMN <columnName> nvarchar(200) [NULL|NOT NULL]
```

**Note** :Don't forget the Null....

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the Full-Text Index that was creating this dependency on the column. Had to completely remove the Full-Text Index, edit the column and rebuild it.