# How to convert a `timestamp without time zone` in a `timestamp with time zone` without getting the ouput in local time zone?

Tags: postgresql

**Context:** I have a column of type `timestamp without time zone` containing timestamps recorded by a datalogger in UTC time. When I import this column in R, the time part is lost (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22899516/10264278) on that). However, I cannot use the argument `as.is = TRUE` as suggested in the answers.
However, when the column type is `timestamp with time zone`, the transfer to R works well.
I do not have admin rights on this database and cannot ALTER tables (or I do not know how to do it properly).

**Problem:** when I convert `timestamp without time zone` into `timestamp with time zone`, the timestamp is displayed in my local time zone (here UTC+1).

**Question:** how to convert a `timestamp without time zone` in a `timestamp with time zone` without getting the ouput in local time zone?

**What I tried:** I got the desired output using `SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';` before the query as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42684544/10264278) but I am wondering if there is a proper solution without having to change the entire time zone of the session as it might have side effects latter on.

Example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-12-01 11:00:00' -- timestamp without tz, recorded by a datalogger in UTC
AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/Universal' -- timestamp with tz, displayed in local tz, considering timestamp from previous line as UTC
```

Output:

> "2022-12-01 12:00:00+01" (timestamp with time zone)

Expected output:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-12-01 11:00:00' -- timestamp without tz, recorded by a datalogger in UTC
AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/Universal' -- timestamp with tz, displayed in local tz, considering timestamp from previous line as UTC
```

> "2022-12-01 11:00:00+00" (timestamp with time zone)

I am not familiar with SQL, please do not hesitate to link this post to an existing one with relevant answers, I might have used the wrong keywords.

Comment: That is impossible. `timestamp with timezone` is *always* formatted according to the current setting of `timezone`. Does R not understand the time zone offset? Perhaps you can report all this as bug in the R driver.

Comment: Ok, as a quick fix I will use `SELECT to_char(TIMESTAMP '2022-12-01 11:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` which converts the column to character and then I can use R functions to convert it back to POSIXct and co.